# replacing css "display:none" value with "display:flex using js

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

i'm attempting to replace a css value "display:none" defined on a div by a "display:flex" using js property .css().
When doing so, **safari on Ipad** ignores the js instruction (i used the prefixes for cross browser compatibility + tried css !important) and instead it applies "display:block" which is the user agent style defaulted value (i have a reset.css in place as well)...it ends up not giving what i'm looking for. However the issue does not occur on desktop browsers. Any tips to override this defaulted value on Ipad please?

Comment: Plz add the relavant code.

Comment: whats the problem in doing something like `node.style.display = "flex"`?

Comment: With no code or link its not easy to help you.

Comment: Why you don't use JQuery ?

Comment: _using js property .css()_     `.css()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: Maybe your iphone IOS or safari are out of date and not support `display:flex`. Old version of OS and Browser maybe need an other css syntax: `display: box`
Take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#browser-support

Comment: thk all but using .addClass() solved my issue and seems a better option than .css() in this case as proposed below by avinash

Comment: FYI, questions about CSS flexbox should be tagged "flexbox", not "flex" -- the latter refers to Apache Flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as below
create a CSS class

```
.temp{
display:flex!important;
}
```

add that class dynamically to the element using addClass function in jquery

```
$(selector).addClass('temp');
```

Comment: Hi , your approach is actually solving the issue and overriding the user agent style defaulted on ipad. thk!