# jQuery .show issue (Safari iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

I have recently started to learn jQuery and have been developing a responsive carousel to practice however I am encountering a strange problem where .show() doesn't seem to work correctly on Safari for the iPad.

The issue I am having is that when I click the left arrow I want the second slide to display however this doesn't seem to work (works in all other browsers including Chrome for the iPad), if I change the code to show the third slide rather than the second it works fine so I think the problem has something to do with displaying an immediate sibling.

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">  
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="slide" data-index="1"></div>
        <div class="slide" data-index="2"></div>
        <div class="slide" data-index="3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow left"></div>
    <div class="arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 }

.carousel {
    padding-top: 40%; /*((slide-height/max-width)*100)*/
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 }

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }

.slide {
    background-size: 100%;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
 }

    .slide:nth-child(1) {
        background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/14mqkpe.png");
        display: block;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(2) {background-image: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/11t5t1h.png")}

    .slide:nth-child(3) {background-image: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2pquruu.png")}   

.arrow {
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 2%;
 }

    .arrow.left {
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        border-left: 3px solid #fff;
        left: 2%;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
     }

    .arrow.right {
        -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        border-right: 3px solid #fff;
        right: 2%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
     }
```

**jQuery**

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var pluginName = "Carousel",
        defaults = {           
        };

    function update_slides(element, options){   
    };

    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = $(element);

        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ; 

        var initials = {        
        }

        $.extend( {}, initials, this.options);    

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();        
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            this.manual_navigation(this.element, this.options)
        },

        manual_navigation: function( element, options ) {
            element.find('.arrow.left').click(function() {
                element.find('.slide[data-index="1"]').removeClass('show');
                element.find('.slide[data-index="1"]').addClass('hide');
                element.find('.slide[data-index="2"]').removeClass('hide');
                element.find('.slide[data-index="2"]').addClass('show');
            });
            element.find('.arrow.right').click(function() {
                element.find('.slide[data-index="3"]').show();
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".carousel").Carousel();
});
```

I think the issue might have something to do with .wrapper having a width of 100% because if I change it to 50% everything seems to work, unfortunately the website I want to use the carousel on needs the width to be 100%.

Thanks for taking a look and hopefully someone has encountered something similar before.

Comment: are you sure `show` is not working?

Comment: `element.find('.slide[data-index="2"]')` returns something?

Comment: I think the issue is show because the click seems to register (I can hide the current slide). I hosted a test version of the slider for testing so if you have an iPad you can check it out at http://guesthouse.cf/slider_test

Comment: @kmsdev If I console.log element.find('.slide[data-index="2"]') it returns Object[div.slide]

Comment: Try to add a class to the object and apply styles from it, as @AvinashPerla  answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd post a solution I came up with, it may not be the best but seems to work. I simply changed the css

```
.slide:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/14mqkpe.png");
    display: block;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {background-image: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/11t5t1h.png")}

.slide:nth-child(3) {background-image: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2pquruu.png")}
```

to the following

```
.slide[data-index="1"] {
        background-image: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/14mqkpe.png");
        display: block;
    }

.slide[data-index="2"] {background-image: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/11t5t1h.png")}

.slide[data-index="3"] {background-image: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2pquruu.png")}
```

and everything seems to work correctly on the iPad, not sure if this is a problem with nth-child and the version of safari on my iPad or whether it is an issue with my code but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

create two css classes

```
.show
{
display:none!important;
}
.hide
{
display:block!important;
}
```

now toggle between the classes when you want to hide or show.

example

```
if($(selector).hasClass('show')){
$(selector).removeClass('show');
$(selector).addClass('hide');
}else{
{
$(selector).removeClass('hide');
$(selector).addClass('show');
}
```

another user has faced the similar issue which got resolved

[replacing css "display:none" value with "display:flex using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210265/replacing-css-displaynone-value-with-displayflex-using-js/30210407?noredirect=1#comment48526944_30210407)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions unfortunately I still seem to get the same results (the first slide will hide but the second won't display) what makes it particularly strange is that if I change it to display the third slide rather than the second then this approach works well (I've updated the site so if you have an iPad you can check the results).

Comment: Hi I am not sure but alert the data-index value and check once I think its logical problem

Comment: I have logged the index values and checked them and everything seems to be ok in that respect. Really stumped by it, must be something specifically to do with the iPad as it works fine on all other browsers. Thanks for the help I will have to try another approach.

Comment: I never worked on Ipad. In these kind of cases I will right specific function for ipad safari and rest of the  browsers. and will call respective function. If possible try this approach

Comment: I have edited my original post to contain all of the code. I think I will have to do as you suggest and write something specific to the iPad, its just finding out what is causing the issue to occur that is the problem.